# Type "any" overriding type checking of function parameters

Tags: typescript

If you try this piece of code:

```
class MyClass {
    TypedFunction(v: number):number {
        return v;
    }
} 

let myClass = new MyClass;
let p1: any = "aaa"; 
document.writeln(String(myClass.TypedFunction(p1)));
```

There is no complain from the TypeScript compiler and the code is correctly executed writing the string "aaa" on the document.

The methode typedFunction expects a number and we use a string in a variable with the type "any" and everything is OK for both compilation and execution.

Can we really trust the type checking at function call in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `any` you point to the compiler that you don't care about type safety. Don't use `any` if you want to guarantee type checks.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling typescript that you will use any so there won't be compile error.

However if you insist on number for input variable. You can us [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if the input is number