# How to enable checking of type Any in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to enable type checking for using type `any` since this is currently allowed:

```
const array: string[] = [];
const anyValue: any = 123;
array.push(anyValue);
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319368/type-any-overriding-type-checking-of-function-parameters) is similar but doesnt provide a solution to let the VSCode know this behaviour is not recommended.

I have enabled `strict` mode in `tsconfig.json` but that doesn't seem to affect the highlighting. Is there a feature to error on the use of `any`? I can't seem to find one in the docs apart from `noImplicitAny`.

Comment: `any` is like an escape hatch from the type system. By design, anything that has type `any` will not be type checked, wherever it is used. In short, there _isn't a way to type check `any`_, since `any` is literally designed to not be type checked. As a solution, you should avoid using `any` wherever you can (in your example, you could just leave it out and would get correct type checking then). If you don't know the type of a value, you can instead use the type `unknown`, which is subject to type checks.

Comment: Hmm okay. I myself wrote `any` in this case to provide a simple example, but in my code I'm making a call to my database which returns `any` because `JSON.parse` is of type `any`. How would I avoid using it then?

Comment: I just tried labeling the return value of this function with type `unknown` which casts an error later on since I'm pushing to a different typed array. Good enough :)