# Enable "noImplicitAny" in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react js application I want to forbid `any` to be used as a type. According to documentation of TS I added this in my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```

After adding this and doing `yarn tsc --noEmit` i don't get any error in my component where I used `any`, ex: `const a:any = 10`

Question: How to enable TS `noImplicitAny` rule in my project?

 NOTE: I am using WebStorm as IDE and expect to underline the TS error when I use `any`, but it also does not happen.

Comment: `const a:any = 10` is not *implicit* `any`, it's explicit. Implicit any would be like `const foo = (bar) => bar`. Here, `bar` is implicit

Comment: `const a:any = 10` is not *implicit*. It's *explicit*. The rule is enabled and works correctly by not failing builds for explicit `any`.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering the same thing! Instead of labeling a variable `any`, you can name them `unkown` which will trigger an error message. Check out my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770823/how-to-enable-checking-of-type-any-in-typescript

Comment: @VLAZ, then what is the rule for explicit any?

Comment: @Riwen, how to prohibit explicit any then using TS?

Comment: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"noImplicitAny": true` will only error *implicit* `any`. `const a:any = 10` won't fail the build because it's **explicit**, as people have rightfully commented.

Typescript doesn't appear to have a rule for explicit `any`s. One option is using [ESLint](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/) and enabling the [`no-explicit-any`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/) rule to achieve what you want.

Comment: "only" is a bit exaggerated :p

Comment: @caTS oh, are there other options? I'd love to check them out!